# jquery messages from en.yml

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a RoR 4 app using Jquery. Jquery has some custom hover over messages, would it be possible to get those messages from RoR's en.yml? I want all localization to happen in one file -  en.yml for faciliatating easy translations to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add your translations to the window-scope.
Just render them in your template as a script tag.

The HTML-Output should be something like that.

```
<script>
    window.snippets = {
        'translationKey': 'Your translated message rendered by RoR'
    };
</script>
```

So you passed the translation to a place where Javascript can access it.